# ruby sort hash based on another hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following two hashes:

```
db = {"1" => "first_name", "2" => "last_name", "5" => "status", "10" => "city"  }
csv = {"1" => "first_name", "2" => "last_name", "5" => "status", "7" => "address", "10" => "city" }
```

I want to order csv based on db, and if there are any keys in csv not in db, then I want to move them to the end of csv, so in the above example the result would look like this:

```
{"1" => "first_name", "2" => "last_name", "5" => "status", "10" => "city", "7" => "address" }
```

Since the key "7" wasn't in db hash, we just moved it to the end of the csv hash.

This is what I tried:

```
db = {"1" => "first_name", "2" => "last_name", "5" => "status", "10" => "city"  }
csv = {"1" => "first_name", "2" => "last_name", "5" => "status", "7" => "address", "10" => "city" }
rejects = csv.reject {|k| db.include? k }
result = csv.keep_if {|k,_| db.include? k }
result.merge!(rejects)
result   
=> {"1"=>"first_name", "2"=>"last_name", "5"=>"status", "10"=>"city", "7"=>"address"}
```

It seems to work. But is it guaranteed to work? Will the merger always put the second hash at the end, or is there  a possibility that the merger could mix the hashes together without consideration of order?

Comment: You don't need to reorder the keys in `csv` that are present in `db`?

Comment: @sawa the keys that are in db that are not in csv should be appended to the end of csv. The order of the keys in db does not matter, but they must all be at the end of csv hash.

Comment: I am not asking about "the keys that are in db that are not in csv", I am asking about "the keys that are in db that are in csv".

Comment: @sawa the keys in csv must match the order of the keys in db. That is a must, but the extras in db can be tossed to the end of csv and order does not matter, as long as they are after the keys that do match between the two hashes.

Comment: Why do you want to sort a hash? It does you no good. Instead, grab the keys, order them how you want, and then use `hash.values_at(*keys)` to grab the values in the order you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
db_keys = db.keys
  #=> ["1", "2", "5", "10"] 
keys = db_keys + (csv.keys-db_keys)
  #=> ["1", "2", "5", "10", "7"] 
Hash[keys.zip(csv.values_at(*keys))]
  #=> { "1"=>"first_name", "2"=>"last_name", "5"=>"status",
  #    "10"=>"city", "7"=>"address"}
```